# Apache2.4 server Falla en iniciar cuando configuras alias en Windows 10

Tags: windows10, apache2

ya lei el manual de apache he hice busquedas en google y https://serverfault.com y https://stackoverflow.com en ingles pero las recomendaciones que consegui son las mismas que ya yo tengo seteadas aca

que quiero en el browser : localhost/vcore/   > y que el navegador me lleve a la web que estoy desarrollando

Mi .conf file

***httpd.conf***:  (*note*: los puntos hacen refererncia al texto estandar el archivo)

```
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
.
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
.
<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /vcore/ "D:/project/code/VCore/"
    .
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
.
.
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Alias
Include conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf
```

ahora en el ***conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf*** file :

```
<VirtualHost vcore:80>
    ServerName vcore.com
    ServerAlias /vcore/ 
    DocumentRoot "D:/project/code/VCore/"
    ErrorLog "D:/project/code/VCore/apache-logs/vcore-ERROR.log"
    CustomLog "D:/project/code/VCore/apache-logs/vcore-acces.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

y finalmente en el archivo ***conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf*** :

```
<Directory "D:/project/code/VCore/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

..... el apache server no arranca,   la unica vez que lo logre arrancar fue cuando agregue el alias `Alias /vcore/ "D:/project/code/VCore/"` en ***httpd.conf***  sin incluir el Include para  ***httpd-alias.conf*** y ***httpd-vhosts.conf***   peor lo que obtuve en el browser fue

**Forbidden**

**You don't have permission to access this resource.**

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Puedes verlo haciendo httpd -t desde consola o intentar iniciarlo desde consola con httpd -k start.

Comment: hola @juan gracias por contestar... aca lo que dice 

AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: @Juan gracias por tu respuesta fue de muchisima ayuda me ayudo a identificar el problema ya esta funcionando

Comment: Las directivas `Allow`, `Deny` y `Order` son obsoletas en Apache 2.4, aunque aún disponibles mediante el módulo `mod_access_compat`. En su lugar debes usar `Require`.

Answer (score 1):

gracias al comentario de @juan logre identificar la lo que pasaba:

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -k start
AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

y eso me aponto en la direccion correcta el file **conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf** estaba quejando en la linea 4 `Order allow, deny` so I comment it `#Order allow, deny`

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -k start
AH00526: Syntax error on line 5 of C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf:
Invalid command 'Allow', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

so hice lo mismo en la linea 5 `#Allow from all`  and apache works!!!

yo no se si apache2.4 cambio algo y ya no esta aceptando estas opciones o si estoy dejando de activar alguna opcion que me permita usar estos settings comentarlos permitio a apache arrancar y la pagina no tienen ningun problema